# Desagrupar marcadores utilizando Google Maps API com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Boa tarde

Como posso desagrupar esse grupo de marcadores que tem localização próxima utilizando o Google Maps API? Pesquisei porém encontrei apenas o MarkerClusterer e outras alternativas que não são oriundas da Google, modificando os ícones padrões, e só encontrei uma que ao clicar sobre um marcador vários outros se desagrupam, porém não é nativo do Google.

Sem falar que o problema é quando o zoom está muito próximo, e os marcadores estão todos concentrados em uma rua por exemplo, como na imagem abaixo, então nesse caso o MarkerClustered não funcionaria.

[image: Grupo de marcadores]

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Elas não pode ser tão próximas assim... você está pegando a LAT,LNG com base em que? apenas endereço SEM o número? tente adicionar o número do endereço que pode melhorar o resultado

Comment: Um tablet/smartphone registra no banco de dados móvel as coordenadas utilizando latitude, longitude e depois sincroniza com o servidor. É o próprio smartphone que utiliza o GPS e pega as informações da localização.

Comment: Quantas casas decimais você está guardando no banco?

Comment: 3 casas decimais, latitude e longitude

Comment: Este é o problema, considere utilizar no mínimo 6 casas. da uma olhada na diferença que é 3 CASAS e 6 CASAS http://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html

Comment: O resultado será mais preciso também @PauloHDSousa?

Comment: Sim, quanto mais casas decimais, mais preciso

Comment: Corrigindo @PauloHDSousa, no banco estava mostrando apenas 3, antes de clicar no campo, porém quando cliquei mostrou 7 casas decimais.

Comment: Então deve estar plotando certo no mapa, bem, a solução mais simples e rápida é você adicionar 2.000 na LAT ou LNG dos endereços

Comment: Quando tive uma necessidade parecida com a sua usei o OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier, veja um exemplo [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837201/29909197#29909197). Caso isto lhe ajuda posso incluir uma resposta para você.

Comment: Obrigado @BrunoCésar, irei testar o OMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme havia citado nos comentários uma alternativa que provavelmente resolve seu problema, mesmo não sendo oficial do Google, é o [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier).

Considerando os pontos abaixo, que estão relativamente próximos:

```
[
   {
      "lat":-27.6142358,
      "lng":-48.4828248
   },
   {
      "lat":-27.6142358,
      "lng":-48.4828248
   },
   {
      "lat":-27.6142358,
      "lng":-48.4828248
   },
   {
      "lat":-27.6142358,
      "lng":-48.4828248
   },
   {
      "lat":-27.6142358,
      "lng":-48.4828248
   }
]
```

Para usarmos basta criarmos o objeto `OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier` informando nosso `map`, algo assim:

```js
var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
```

Depois disto iremos falar para ele qual será a ação ao clicar em um dos marcadores, depois de já ter exibido o efeito *spider*, que no nosso caso será substituir o conteúdo da `infoWindow` e exibi-la:

```js
oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) {
    infowindow.setContent(marker.description);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Também iremos falar que quando se expandir, ou seja, o efeito *spider*, caso a `infoWindow` esteja sendo apresentada, para que ela seja fechada, desta forma:

```js
oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
    infowindow.close();
});
```

Por último, sempre que criarmos um marcado iremos falar para o `OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier` sobre sua criação, adicionando-o desta forma:

```js
oms.addMarker(marker);
```

Veja um exemplo completo abaixo:

```js
var map;
var oms;

var gm = google.maps;

var infowindow = new gm.InfoWindow(); 

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new gm.LatLng(-27.6142358, -48.4828248)
  };

  map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), mapOptions);

  oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);

  oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) {
    infowindow.setContent(marker.description);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
    infowindow.close();
  });


  function addPosition(items) {
    var content = '<div>' +
        '<h3>' + items.position + '</h3>' +
        '<p>Latitude: ' + items.lat + ' - Longitude: ' + items.lng + '</p>' +
        '</div>';

    var myLatLng = new gm.LatLng(items.lat, items.lng);
    var marker = new gm.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map
    });

    marker.description = content;

    oms.addMarker(marker);
  }

  var jsonPoints =  '[' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6142558,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4828548' +
      '   },' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6143558,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4828548' +
      '   },' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6142558,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4878248' +
      '   },' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6144351,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4828248' +
      '   },' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6143358,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4928248' +
      '   }' +
      ']';

  var points = $.parseJSON(jsonPoints);

  $.each(points, function(i, obj) {
    var item = new Object();
    item.position = "Posição - " + (i + 1);
    item.lat = obj.lat;
    item.lng = obj.lng;
    addPosition(item);
  });
}

gm.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#mapcanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js"></script>

<div id="mapcanvas" />
```

Perceba que em maior zoom é apresentado o efeito *spider*, mas caso estejamos com o zoom bem alto este efeito não mais será necessário

Não sei se é exatamente sua necessidade, mas espero ter ajudado :)

Answer (score 0):

Estimado

Sabes porque cuando agrego una nueva coordenada deja de funcionar ejemplo:

```
var jsonPoints =  '[' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6142558,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4828548' +
      '   },' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6143558,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4828548' +
      '   },' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6142558,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4878248' +
      '   },' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6144351,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4828248' +
      '   },' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6143358,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4928248' +
      '   }' +
      '   {' +
      '      "lat":-27.6143358,' +
      '      "lng":-48.4928248' +
      '   }' +
      ']';
```

Saludos Pablo.

Comment: Se você tem uma nova pergunta, por favor utilize o botão [Faça uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). A área que você usou para postar a pergunta é somente para respostas.